# How to wait for async competition handlers in swift method

Tags: delegates, swift2

I am using [SwiftHttp](https://github.com/daltoniam/SwiftHTTP) for my web api calls. I have created a generic helper method to get data from Web Api and return data in completion handler. here is code.

```
public func getArray(let apiUri:String, let token:String, let parms:HTTPParameterProtocol? , completionHandler:(data:NSMutableArray?,error:NSError?)->Void) ->Void
{
    do {

        var header:[String:String]? = nil
        if token != ""{
            header = ["Authorization":"Bearer \(token)"]
        }

        let opt = try HTTP.GET(_baseurl + apiUri, parameters: parms, headers: header)

        opt.start { response in
            if let err = response.error {
                completionHandler(data:nil,error:err)                    
            }
            let data = response.data as NSData                
            do {
                if let mutableArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSMutableArray {

                    completionHandler(data:mutableArray, error:nil)
                }
            }
            catch let er as NSError{
                completionHandler(data:nil, error:er)
            }
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        completionHandler(data:nil,error:error)
    }

}
```

It is working fine.

Now in my caller method I want to call this method for 5(or more) times in single method and that method also has completion handler I want that this methods' completionHalder will only be called once all the 5 web api calls are completed. I am new to swift

```
  public func loadAccountAndAuthorize(token:String, completionHander:(isLoaded:Bool,user:Account)->()){
   let myApi:WebApiHelper = WebApiHelper.WebApi
   myApi.getArray("User", token: token, parms: nil) { (data, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            completionHander(isLoaded: false, user: Account())
        }
        else {
        }
      })
    myApi.getArray("secondAPi", token: token, parms: nil) { (data, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            completionHander(isLoaded: false, user: Account())
        }
        else {
        }
      })

    myApi.getArray("thirdAPi", token: token, parms: nil) { (data, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            completionHander(isLoaded: false, user: Account())
        }
        else {
        }
      })/// there can be more web api calls...


    //But This should be called when all web api calls are completed..
    completionHander(isLoaded: true, user: Account())
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP class in that library is subclassed from NSOperationQueue, so the simplest solution would be to put all of those operations on a queue and create a new [NSBlockOperation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSBlockOperation_class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/c:objc(cs)NSBlockOperation) that you also put on the queue but with dependencies on all of the other operations.

So change `getArray()` to use the operation queue example in his Readme.md and have it return the created operation. Then change the second bit of code to create a block operation containing the final completion handler and add each returned operation from `getArray()` as a dependency, then put it on the same queue as all the other operations.

`loadAccountAndAuthorize` would look something like:

```
let completionOperation = NSBlockOperation {  
    completionHander(isLoaded: true, user: Account()) 
}

let op1 = myApi.getArray("User", token: token, parms: nil) { /* all the per request completion stuff */ })
completionOperation.addDependency(op1)
// Same for all the other operations

operationQueue.addOperation(completionOperation) // Will not run until all dependencies are complete.
```

You'll need to be a bit careful if your final completion block depends on the results of all the others because all of this is now happening on different threads and setting flags etc might result synchronisation issues. It might be a good idea to use GCD to dispatch the work in the completion handlers on the main queue. In fact if they do UI updates, it would be mandatory.